# QGIS 2.14 Symbol Colors Changing on Zoom

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm having this problem with Rule Based Symbols.

I am able to change the color of a dot based on the name field but when I zoom in and out the colors bounce around to other dots.

By zooming in and out of my map, the colors change with no regards to the color rule I set.

I can not figure it out, maybe its a rendering thing but I'm not sure. Attached are screenshots. All these dots are supposed to be the brown like color. If I zoom in closer they will all turn brown.

[image: Zoomed Out]

[image: Zoomed In]

[image: Express]

Comment: What is the data type (shp, gdb, PostGIS...etc) and what software version are you using?

Comment: Using a PostGIS Database and I'm on QGIS 2.14. This has worked no problem on 2.4 , 2.6 and 2.8.

Comment: Can you share more details? Eg screenshots of your rule setup could help

Comment: Rule Formula is  (CASE WHEN NAME= 'Starbucks' THEN color_rgb (0,225,225) END)

Comment: just a thought - could you have overlapping points?

Comment: Nope and even if that were overlapping dots they would be the same value so the colors should stay the same. This layer worked just fine in 2.8. I'm starting to think i might just be a bug in 2.14.

Comment: 2.14 has been out for a while, with many bug fixes. Maybe it's time to update to 2.14.8.

Comment: I was on 2.14.6. I just tested it out on 2.14.8 same thing.

Comment: It seems to really only effect dots that are not included in the rule. Like they take on the color of the closest dot until you zoom in really close.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Looks like in the new 2.14 you need to specify an "ELSE" color. Where as in 2.8 if a value wasn't included in a rule formula it defaulted to the base color. Now you have to do that in the rule expression or QGIS will keep changing the color of unspecified values.

ELSE color_rgb (0,0,0) END = Default color to black if NAME not specified.

Comment: Hmmm - that doesn't sound right. Null results should fallback to the defined color. Let me investigate....